# How to stop the finish() method after press back button in android?

Tags: java, android

Can I check some condition in finish()

if the condition is success, continue to back to previous

else, stop the finish, and stay in current activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is, Override your activity's `finish()`

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    if( bLetsFinish ){
        super.finish(); //This will finish the activity and take you back
    }else{
        //Do whatever it is that you want to do
        return;
    }
}
```

However, note that this function will be called every time the Activity wants to finish(), eg you rotate your phone and the Activity is recreated. In this case your old Activity will not finish() and I am not sure how the behavior of the Activity destruction would be.

Answer (score 8):

You can catch the "back" press event by overriding `onBackPressed()` in your activity. If you have some condition in which you don't want to finish the activity, do not call `super.onBackPressed()` in that method.

However, be sure you do call `super.onBackPressed()` if that condition is not met.

Comment: I second that.... or you can also call this.finish() inside onBackPressed() instead of super.onBackPressed()

Comment: @KKD `super.onBackPressed()` calls `finish()` on pre-Honeycomb versions, but has `Fragment` support post-Honeycomb (and in the support package). It's best to call the `super` to avoid performing unexpected behavior, unless that's your intent.

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(success){
            finish();
       }
      return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

you can use the above method or below method to do your task

```
public void onBackPressed(){
if(success){
finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (success)
        super.onBackPressed();
    else // Do what you want to do
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Also please refrain from using code-only answers, instead try to explain the solution as use the code as an example.